# Nested Compositte View In Marionette - Outer View is Taking Last inner View Value in Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am Facing an issue when i submitted My new Screen.

When i search and retrieve a record i am getting a model in this way

Model Structure....

```
myModel  - attributes - opt         : "AND"
                 isNestedView : false
                rows          : model(1) - attributes  - opt  : "OR"
                                                      isNestedView : true
                                                      rows : model ...
                                model (2)- attributes - opt  : "AND"
                                                      isNestedView : true
                                                      rows : model ...
```

My code is Like this

```
var Layout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({


template : '#abc',
initialize : function(){
..........//some code
},
onShow : function(){

this.someRegion.show(new CompositeView({model : myModel}));
}
});

var CompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

template : "#bcd",
initialize : function(){
//.....some code
},
getItemView : function(item)    {
      if(item.get("isNested") == true)  {
            return CompositeView;
      } else  {
           return ItemView            }
},
onShow : function(){
//someCode
}
});

ItemView  = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
//taking inner rows
})
```

What is the real problem is when i change my Last itemview opt value to OR my outer CompositeView model value also changing .i do not want that ,i could'nt find a solution on it.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're using a CompositeView, but not passing in a collection as well as a model...  Seems to me you need both.

Comment: myModel.attributes.rows - is a collection

Comment: I had this issue only when submit and retrive but rendering was fine , i resolved it myself by using jquery